# Setting up Odoo 14 + HTTPS through nginx

Tags: nginx, odoo, subdomain, assets, odoo-14

I've been developing a deployed Odoo v14 instance which I used to access using the IP.
My intention was to access this instance using a subdomain I own, I have registered domainname.com and created an A record called crm.domainname.com targeting the IP where my Odoo instance is.
The link was working correctly but I want to hide the IP and only display crm.domainname.com when Odoo is accessed so I installed Nginx to configure the domain and use it as reverse proxy.

Here is where my problem comes, I don't have much experience configuring Nginx but after some research and experimenting I came up with this configurations (but I think they are redundant)

file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  crm.domainname.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/crm_domainname_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/crm_domainname_com.key;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
        }
     }
}
```

and for both `/ect/nginx/sites-available/odoo` and `/ect/nginx/sites-enabled/odoo` which don't seem to be loading at all

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
 server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
 server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

# http -> https
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name crm.domainname.com;
#   return 301 https://crm.domainname.com$request_uri;
rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
 listen 443 ssl default_server;
 server_name crm.domainname.com;
 proxy_read_timeout 720s;
 proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
 proxy_send_timeout 720s;

 # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

 # SSL parameters
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/crm_domainname_com.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/crm_domainname_com.key;
 ssl_session_timeout 30m;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM$....
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 # log
 access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

 # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
 location /longpolling {
   proxy_pass http://odoochat;
 }

 # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
 location / {
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://odoo;
 }

#   location ~* /web/static/ {
#       proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
#       proxy_buffering    on;
#       expires 864000;
#       proxy_pass http://odoo;
#  }

#  common gzip
 gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json applicat$
 gzip on;
}
```

finally for my `odoo-server.conf` file

```
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
db_host = False
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = False
db_port = False
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template0
db_user = odoo
dbfilter =
demo = {}
email_from = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
http_enable = True
http_interface = 127.0.0.1
http_port = 8069
import_partial =
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560
limit_memory_soft = 2147483648
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 60
limit_time_real = 120
limit_time_real_cron = -1
list_db = True
log_db = False
log_db_level = warning
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
longpolling_port = 8072
max_cron_threads = 1
osv_memory_age_limit = False
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path =
pidfile =
proxy_mode = True
reportgz = False
screencasts =
screenshots = /tmp/odoo_tests
server_wide_modules = base,web
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_enable = False
test_file =
test_tags = None
transient_age_limit = 1.0
translate_modules = ['all']
unaccent = False
upgrade_path =
without_demo = False
workers = 2
```

After running all this configurations and restarting Odoo and Nginx I can access crm.domainname.com but assets like CSS and JS are not loading. Chrome console shows the following error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

[image]

And when I login with my username and password all I see is a blank screen. Chrome console shows the same error as in login screen but with `status 200` and sometimes this error appears too:
`Uncaught TypeError: odoo.define is not a function`

I've tried regenerating the assets but I've been only able to delete them using
`DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE url LIKE '/web/content/%';` but It may have worsened things.

What am I getting wrong? I can't find the solution regarding this missing assets anywhere nor the correct nginx.conf and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to solve this problem where assets where not loading and it was almost all a misconfiguration of my Nginx!

First of all, in file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
I've deleted the server block inside http,
I had to include the sites-enabled configuration and remove the server directives to main HTTP block.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/odoo;
}
```

My server directives inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/odoo` now looks like this

```
*Old config*
. . .
#http-> https
    server {
       server_name crm.domainname.com;
       return 301 https://crm.domainname.com$request_uri;
    }
#https
    server {
       listen 443 ssl http2;
       server_name crm.domainname.com;
       . . .
       *More config*
       . . .
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
       # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
       location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://odoo;
       }

       location /longpolling {
            proxy_pass http://odoochat;
       }

       location ~* /web/static/ {
           proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
           proxy_buffering    on;
           expires 864000;
           proxy_pass http://odoo;
       }
    }
```

Finally I added the interfaces at the end of `/etc/odoo-server.conf`

```
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
netrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
```

Now everything is working, my subdomain is redirecting to https and correctly displaying Odoo and loading all its assets even if I'm not in debug mode!